# How can I assign nil to a binding object in SwiftUI?

Tags: binding, swiftui

I want to default returnGroup as nil inside the init method , but I get the follow error 
Nil default argument value cannot be converted to type 'Binding'

Would like to know how to set the binding to nil ?

```
class DisplayPlayGroupViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Binding var closeFlag : Bool
    @Binding var returnGroup : PlayGroup?


    init(closeFlag : Binding<Bool> , returnGroup : Binding<PlayGroup?> = nil){ //<----Error
        self._closeFlag = closeFlag
        self._returnGroup = returnGroup
    }
```

Comment: `@Binding` in `ObservableObject`? Would you explain what are you going to do? Because, actually, by concept, `ObservableObject` is a *source of data*, but `@Binding` is a `linked target`.

Comment: Sometime , the view will act like a popup form other view to make selection , so it can call directly without a return value and call by a popup and return a value for selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to assign nil to the binding set it using .constant(nil). Here's how you can do it.

```
init(closeFlag : Binding<Bool> , returnGroup : Binding<PlayGroup?> = .constant(nil)) {
    self._closeFlag = closeFlag
    self._returnGroup = returnGroup
}
```